# Can an open interval be bounded?

Tags: general-topology

I have a question which is as follows:

Let $A = \{(-\cos x, \sin x)\} \in \mathbb{R^2} : x \in (-\pi, \pi)$

I have to justify what kind of set it is. I said it's an open and bounded set. I would say it is bounded since cos and sin are both bounded functions. However, the only thing that I'm unsure of is the fact that its only defined at $x \in (-\pi, \pi)$. I'm guessing that it doesn't really matter if its not defined at $-\pi$ or $\pi$ because the values at that points are irrelevant for concluding whether A is bounded or not. And as for whether the set is open or not, I said that it's open since the domain is open since the limit points $-\pi$ and $\pi$ are not included in the set.

Comment: It is just bounded, nothing more.

Comment: Have you sketched the graph of the set in $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$?

Comment: To answer the title question, consider the open interval $(0,1)$

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales i just tried that and it made it more clear thanks.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner so in general boundedness of a set has to do with finding a number M such that the difference between any two points in a set is less than the number M right?

Comment: That's the idea, @UnKnoWnZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is simply the unit circle minus the point $\langle 1,0\rangle$, so it is indeed bounded: every point of $A$ is exactly $1$ unit from the origin. It is not, however, open: it does not contain an open ball around any of its points. It is also not closed, since $\langle 1,0\rangle$ is in its closure.

It is true $(-\pi,\pi)$ is open in $\Bbb R$ and that $A$ is the image of that open set under the continuous function

$$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2:t\mapsto\langle-\cos t,\sin t\rangle\,,$$

but that function is not open: it does not take open subsets of $\Bbb R$ to open subsets of $\Bbb R^2$.